# Performing sobel filters on rgb color components

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, scikit-image

I'm trying to separate an image into it's rgb color components, and then trying to perform sobel h and v filters on each of the color component images. I'm not really sure what the problem is, but I'm getting the following divide by 0 error. I think it might be because my u and v are turning out to be the exact same array.

**Error**

```
/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/temp/A2.py:51: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  theta = 0.5 * np.arctan(2 * gxy / (gxx - gyy))
/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/temp/A2.py:51: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  theta = 0.5 * np.arctan(2 * gxy / (gxx - gyy))
/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/temp/A2.py:54: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  fTheta = np.sqrt(0.5 * ((gxx + gyy) + (gxx - gyy) * np.cos(2 * theta) + (2 * gxy * np.sin(2 * theta))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/A1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 51, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
```

**Code**

```
import skimage.filters as filt
import numpy as np
def color_dot_product(A, B):
    return np.sum(A.conj() * B, axis=2)


mushroom = io.imread('mushroom.jpg')
I = util.img_as_float(mushroom)
  red = I[:, :, 0]  # Zero out contribution from green
  blue = I[:,:,1]
  green = I[:,:,2]

  # Compute horizontal and vertical derivatives of red, blue and green channels through applying sobel filters
  u = I.copy()
  u[:, :, 0] = filt.sobel_h(red)
  u[:, :, 1] = filt.sobel_h(green)
  u[:, :, 2] = filt.sobel_h(blue)
  v = I.copy()
  v[:, :, 0] = filt.sobel_v(red)
  v[:, :, 1] = filt.sobel_v(green)
  v[:, :, 2] = filt.sobel_v(blue)
  gxx = color_dot_product(u, u)
  gyy = color_dot_product(v, v)
  gxy = color_dot_product(u, v)

  # Calculate gradient direction (direction of the largest colour change)
  theta = 0.5 * np.arctan(2 * gxy / (gxx - gyy))

  # Calculate the magnitude of the rate of change
  fTheta = np.sqrt(0.5 * ((gxx + gyy) + (gxx - gyy) * np.cos(2 * theta) + (2 * gxy * np.sin(2 * theta))))
```

Comment: if gxx == gyy you get to divide by zero

Comment: Yes I understood that already, but I think that gxx and gyy might be equal because u and v are equal

Comment: any single index is equal ... you can always print things to see what they look like ... or use breakpoints to examine them `numpy([1,2,3])/numpy([1,2,0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dividing by an image like this, it is very likely that some pixel has a value of zero, and thus you get a division by zero.

This is typically avoided by explicitly testing each pixel for zero before dividing, or if the divisor is non-negative, adding a very small value.

But in this case you don’t need to divide at all. The function [`atan2`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) takes two input arguments, such that `atan2(y,x)` is equivalent to `atan(y/x)`. Except that it returns an angle in the range (-π,π] (i.e. it gives you the full 360 degree range of angles). I linked to Wikipedia above because `atan2` is a generic function that exists in all languages. Except in NumPy it is called `arctan2` (weird desire to be different, I guess?). So replace:

```
theta = 0.5 * np.arctan(2 * gxy / (gxx - gyy))
```

with:

```
theta = 0.5 * np.arctan2(2 * gxy, gxx - gyy)
```

---

The `gxx`, `gyy`, `gxy` triplet you compute looks a lot like the structure tensor. If this is what you intend to compute, you need to add an additional blurring to each of these three components. This causes the gradient information to be averaged locally, yielding fewer locations with a zero gradient.

Comment: That seems correct, I ended up just adding this in at the beginning of my program `np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')` to ignore the times I divide by zero. Would this be good enough?

Comment: @Jacob: I would prefer computing correct angles. What is wrong with `atan2`? Silencing errors is like shoving the dust underneath the carpet. You can't see it any more, but it's still there and it still can cause health problems. :)

Comment: That's just what I used, this was an assignment with a due date. I assumed that my program was just not including the pixels that caused the divide by 0 error.

Comment: No, it's still dividing by zero. As long as you're not doing `0/0`, division by zero yields infinity. `atan(inf)==pi/2`, so you get the right result. But if both `gxy` and `gxx-gyy` are zero (this happens in a uniform region in the image), you get NaN, and then `atan(NaN)==NaN`.